# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio: library references

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, migration

Ok, so here's the deal. Recently I've found out, that Eclipse will no longer be receiving support in matters of Android development and that Android Studio is the go-to IDE for this task. I've checked the newest Studio version and am pretty stoked to try out some new tools, but here's my predicament.

I want to migrate a big project from Eclipse to Studio. So I've followed the instructions on the official developer website https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html
I generated the build.gradle file for my project and imported the file that was generated in my main project, but the problem is that my main project references many other Eclipse library (such as FacebookSDK for login) projects that exist in my workspace. And after I've imported the gradle file into Studio, I'm getting missing dependencies, for these projects.

Could anyone please guide me through the process of migrating correctly or link a sollution, because all I seem to find, applies to projects without external dependencies. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "project structure" in "File" menu.
2. Then select the "Dependencies" tab. (Make sure your App is selected on the left)
3. Choose "Add File Dependency" and choose your libraries from the Libs folder of your App.
4. Click "Apply"

Note: In case of library projects like facebook, you have to choose "Add module dependency"(in step 3) after importing the facebook library project as a module in the Android Studio.